# Debian DHCPv6 get static configured IPv6

Tags: linux, debian, dhcp, ipv6

I configured the DHCPv6 server to return a fixed IPv6 for a specific DUID, how can I get this IP on a Debian client? If I release the current lease with

```
dhclient -6 -r
```

the current DUID is lost and the DHCP does not return the correct IP when requesting a new lease as the DUID is regenerated.

Comment: Are you sure you used the correct DUID? Where did you get it from?

Comment: @MichaelHampton It's generated the first time using the dhclient

Comment: Which DHCP server are you using? The ability to configure non-dynamic stuff varies greatly per DHCP server-side and most of them are really bad at it. (Full disclosure: I'm the author of DHCPKit, which specialises in static assignments, so I'm biased :)

Comment: @SanderSteffann I'm using whatever pfsense router is using (https://pfsense.org/), logs are saying "Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.3.4"

Comment: @SanderSteffann But I think it's working fine, when I remove all but the first line (the DUID) from /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.lease, I'm getting my configured IP after doing a network restart

Comment: @CalibeR.50: ok, the server isn't the problem then. Then check the IAID the client uses. Does that change?